# Duplicate list items in adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

AsyncTask:

```
class mydata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle("Fetching");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Response = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(Constantt.PendingOrderCustomerWiseORDERURL + "18");
            rowItems = new ArrayList<PendingOrderDataModel>();

            try {
                 dataModel = new PendingOrderDataModel();
                _jsonarray = new JSONArray(Response);
                for (int i = 0; i < _jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    _jsobject = _jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    dataModel.setCreatedOn(_jsobject.getString("CreatedOn"));
                    dataModel.setDeliveryAddress(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryAddress"));
                    dataModel.setDeliveryTime(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryTime"));
                    dataModel.setId(_jsobject.getString("Id"));
                    dataModel.setStatus(_jsobject.getString("Status"));
                    dataModel.setTotal(_jsobject.getString("Total"));
                    dataModel.setUserDetailId(_jsobject.getString("UserDetailId"));

                    rowItems.add(dataModel);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Response", Response);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            PendingOrderAdapter adapter = new PendingOrderAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.pendingorderlist_item ,rowItems);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class PendingOrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PendingOrderDataModel> {
    Context context;
    List<PendingOrderDataModel> rowItems;
    public  PendingOrderAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,List<PendingOrderDataModel> items)
    {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView orderridtext;
        TextView orderdatetext;
        TextView orderamounttext;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pendingorderlist_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.orderridtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_order_id);
            holder.orderdatetext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_order_date);
            holder.orderamounttext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_item_total_amount);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PendingOrderDataModel rowItem = (PendingOrderDataModel) getItem(position);


        holder.orderridtext.setText("BHM" +rowItem.getId());
        holder.orderdatetext.setText(rowItem.getDeliveryTime());
        holder.orderamounttext.setText(rowItem.getTotal());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

When I run this AsyncTask, same item is displayed. While in background, when I debug, it sets different data, but in adapter class we are able to get the same data. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Why is the same data printed in the list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `doInBackground()` inside `try` block code from

```
dataModel = new PendingOrderDataModel();
_jsonarray = new JSONArray(Response);
for (int i = 0; i < _jsonarray.length(); i++) {
     _jsobject = _jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     dataModel.setCreatedOn(_jsobject.getString("CreatedOn"));
     dataModel.setDeliveryAddress(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryAddress"));
     dataModel.setDeliveryTime(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryTime"));
     dataModel.setId(_jsobject.getString("Id"));
     dataModel.setStatus(_jsobject.getString("Status"));
     dataModel.setTotal(_jsobject.getString("Total"));
     dataModel.setUserDetailId(_jsobject.getString("UserDetailId"));
     rowItems.add(dataModel);
}
```

to

```
_jsonarray = new JSONArray(Response);
for (int i = 0; i < _jsonarray.length(); i++) {
     dataModel = new PendingOrderDataModel();
     _jsobject = _jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     dataModel.setCreatedOn(_jsobject.getString("CreatedOn"));
     dataModel.setDeliveryAddress(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryAddress"));
     dataModel.setDeliveryTime(_jsobject.getString("DeliveryTime"));
     dataModel.setId(_jsobject.getString("Id"));
     dataModel.setStatus(_jsobject.getString("Status"));
     dataModel.setTotal(_jsobject.getString("Total"));
     dataModel.setUserDetailId(_jsobject.getString("UserDetailId"));
     rowItems.add(dataModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set data in `getview` like this :

```
 holder.orderridtext.setText("BHM" +this.rowItems.get(position).getId());
    holder.orderdatetext.setText(this.rowItems.get(position).getDeliveryTime());
    holder.orderamounttext.setText(this.rowItems.get(position).getTotal());
```

or change this :

```
 PendingOrderDataModel rowItem = rowItems.get(position);


    holder.orderridtext.setText("BHM" +rowItem.getId());
    holder.orderdatetext.setText(rowItem.getDeliveryTime());
    holder.orderamounttext.setText(rowItem.getTotal());
```